# how do i get my app to this kind of level?

Tags: android, graphics, menu, scroll, sprite

There is that app called "turkey blast: reloaded" (link below). The graphics and animation of the game are amazing! Also it is 2d but looks like 3d, I'm not sure how to explain it. Anyways, I am also making an app which is quite different from that (nothing alike..) but I love the menu and the sound and the graphics of this game. The game that I'm working on is about to be finished but its not even close to that kind of level... One of the things that interest me the most in this app is the graphics. How can I make a game with this kind of graphics? I have someone that draws the sprites for me but its hand-drawn, what kind of program do they use? also, how did they make that menu? (all the items in the menu are arraged in a way that you can scoll in them <------> to get to the item that you want.) I am just using texture and texture region. Thanks!

Turkey Blast: Reloaded
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ezone.Turkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make a game with this kind of graphics? I have someone that
>   draws the sprites for me but its hand-drawn,

If you want pro graphics you will need to hire a pro artist. There are several websites where you can find one, including guru.com, odesk.com, etc.

Comment: What about the menu? how did they do that?